# Convert std::chrono::system_clock::time_point to struct timeval and back

Tags: c++, c, c++11

I´m writing a C++ code that needs to access an old C library that uses timeval as a representation of the current time.

In the old package to get the current date/time we used:

```
struct timeval dateTime;
gettimeofday(&dateTime, NULL);

function(dateTime); // The function will do its task
```

Now I need to use C++ chrono, something as:

```
    system_clock::time_point now = system_clock::now();
    struct timeval dateTime;

    dateTime.tv_sec = ???? // Help appreaciated here
    dateTime.tv_usec = ???? // Help appreaciated here

    function(dateTime);
```

Later in code I need the way back, building a `time_point` variable from the returned `struct timeval`:

```
    struct timeval dateTime;
    function(&dateTime);

    system_clock::time_point returnedDateTime = ?? // Help appreacited
```

I´m using C++11.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Edited to use `time_val` instead of free vars]

Assuming you trust your `system_clock` with milliseconds accuracy, you can go like this:

```
  struct timeval dest;
  auto now=std::chrono::system_clock::now();
  auto millisecs=
    std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        now.time_since_epoch()
    );;
  dest.tv_sec=millisecs.count()/1000;
  dest.tv_usec=(millisecs.count()%1000)*1000;

  std::cout << "s:" << dest.tv_sec << " usec:" << dest.tv_usec << std::endl;
```

Use `std::chrono::microseconds` in `duration_cast` and adjust your (div/mod) code accordingly for the higher precision - take care on how much you trust the accuracy of the values you obtain.

The conversion back is:

```
  timeval src;

  // again, trusting the value with only milliseconds accuracy
  using dest_timepoint_type=std::chrono::time_point<
    std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::milliseconds
  >;
  dest_timepoint_type converted{
    std::chrono::milliseconds{
      src.tv_sec*1000+src.tv_usec/1000
    }
  };

  // this is to make sure the converted timepoint is indistinguishable by one
  // issued by the system_clock
  std::chrono::system_clock::time_point recovered =
      std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::system_clock::duration>(converted)
  ;
```

Comment: Should probably assign to `dateTime.tv_sec` and `dateTime.tv_usec` since the goal is to end up with a valid `timeval` struct.

Comment: The `l` in `millisecs.count()/1000l;` and `dest.tv_usec=millisecs.count()%1000l;`  is certainly not needed.  A minor issue.

Answer (score 5):

Here is how to do the conversion both without using manual conversion factors, or depending upon the unspecified rounding mode of `time_t`:

```
timeval
to_timeval(std::chrono::system_clock::time_point tp)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto s = time_point_cast<seconds>(tp);
    if (s > tp)
        s = s - seconds{1};
    auto us = duration_cast<microseconds>(tp - s);
    timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = s.time_since_epoch().count();
    tv.tv_usec = us.count();
    return tv;
}

std::chrono::system_clock::time_point
to_time_point(timeval tv)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return system_clock::time_point{seconds{tv.tv_sec} + microseconds{tv.tv_usec}};
}
```

`to_timeval` takes care to round the `tp` down (in case it is negative).  The POSIX spec is a bit vague on this but I'm assuming that `timeval` represents time points prior to the epoch with negative `tv_sec` values, and then positive `tv_usec` values.  Then it is a simple operation to find the `microseconds` since the last `second`.

If I'm incorrect about my assumption (and a more precise POSIX spec can be found), `<chrono>` has the power to model whatever the heck it does.

The reverse conversion, assuming the conventions above, is incredibly readable.  It requires no comment.

This can all be tested like this:

```
timeval
make_timeval(time_t s, long us)
{
    timeval tv;
    tv.tv_sec = s;
    tv.tv_usec = us;
    return tv;
}

bool
operator==(timeval x, timeval y)
{
    return x.tv_sec == y.tv_sec && x.tv_usec == y.tv_usec;
}

int
main()
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    assert(make_timeval(0, 0) == to_timeval(system_clock::time_point{}));
    assert(make_timeval(1, 0) == to_timeval(system_clock::time_point{seconds{1}}));
    assert(make_timeval(1, 400000) == to_timeval(system_clock::time_point{seconds{1} + microseconds{400000}}));
    assert(make_timeval(-1, 400000) == to_timeval(system_clock::time_point{seconds{-1} + microseconds{400000}}));

    assert(to_time_point(make_timeval(0, 0)) == system_clock::time_point{});
    assert(to_time_point(make_timeval(1, 0)) == system_clock::time_point{seconds{1}});
    assert(to_time_point(make_timeval(1, 400000)) == system_clock::time_point{seconds{1} + microseconds{400000}});
    assert(to_time_point(make_timeval(-1, 400000)) == system_clock::time_point{seconds{-1} + microseconds{400000}});
}
```

This is all predicated on the assumption that the epoch for `timeval` and `system_clock` are identical.  This is not specified, but is true for all existing implementations.  With any luck we can standardize this existing practice in the near future.

Be aware that in POSIX `timeval` is used both as a `time_point` and a `duration`.  So `to_time_point` could result in a run time error if the `timeval` is currently representing a time duration.  And `to_timeval` could result in a run time error if the client interprets the result as a time duration.

Comment: `time_point_cast` rounds down only for values of `tp` that come after the epoch.  For values prior to the epoch `time_point_cast` rounds up.  Using C++17 or later the combination of `time_point_cast` and this `if` can be replaced with a simple:  `auto s = floor<seconds>(tp);`.

Answer (score 4):

See `std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t()`, which converts the `time_point` to a `time_t`, which becomes your `tv_sec`. You don't get `tv_usec`, you can set it 0; or you could fiddle with a few other things, including `duration_cast`, in order to extract fractions of a second from your `time_point`.

`from_time_t`() does the reverse.